# Как можно записать 0 1 2 3 4 5

Tags: java

Как можно записать числа k в массив и повторив это до того момента как массив закончится, то есть, чтобы в массиве хранились числа(к примеру возьмём 5) arr[0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a[] = new int[20];
    int k, temp = 0, arrlength;

    k = sc.nextInt();
    
    if(k <= 0) {
      // input element into array
      for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
      }
    

      // output array before
      System.out.print("Array before: ");
      for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
      }    
  
      // bubble sort
      for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){  
        for(int j=1; j < (a.length-i); j++){
          if(a[j-1] > a[j]){  
            temp = a[j-1];  
            a[j-1] = a[j];  
            a[j] = temp; 
          }
        }
      }
  
      // pushes all zeros to end of an array
      int count = 0; 
  
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] != 0) {
          a[count++] = a[i];
        }
      }
      while (count < a.length){
        a[count++] = 0;
      }

    }

    else {
      int number = 0;
      for(int i=0; i<=k; i++) {
        a[i] = number++;
      }
      
      // pushes all zeros to end of an array
      // int count = 0; 
  
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] != 0) {
          a[count++] = a[i];
        }
      }
      while (count < a.length) {
        a[count++] = 0;
      }
    }

    // output array after
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Array after: ");
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Ну вы ведь уже знаете про циклы, так в чём проблема?

Comment: Зачем в вопросе простыня кода, к вопросу не относящаяся?

Comment: @MBo не получается записать в массив [0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,..., до 20 элемента массива]
```
int number = 0;
      for(int i=0; i<=k; i++) {
        a[i] = number++;
      }
```

Comment: Иcпользуйте или два цикла, или операцию взятия остатка по модулю %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Специально для заполнения массива при помощи некой функции от индекса существует набор стандартных методов (перегруженных в зависимости от типа массива) [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-int:A-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-), и здесь функцией-генератором значений будет достаточно простая лямбда `i -> i % 6`.

Таким образом при помощи следующего лаконичного кода можно получить желаемый массив:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt(); // размер массива
int[] arr = new int[n];

Arrays.setAll(arr, i -> i % 6);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Аналогично можно сгенерировать массив при помощи Stream API, в частности используя [`IntStream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-), в которой придётся задать начальное значение, а также реализовать инкремент:

```java
int[] arr2 = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> (i + 1) % 6).limit(n).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
```

Результаты выполнения:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a =new int[20];
        
        for(int i=0, k =0; i< a.length;i++, k++){
if(k>5) k=0;  
a[i]=k;}
System.out.println( Arrays.toString(a) );
    
    }
}
```

#2

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a =new int[20];
        int[] b = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
        for(int i=0,k=0; i< a.length;i++,k++){
if(k == b.length) k=0;  
a[i]=b[k];}
System.out.println( Arrays.toString(a) );
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Знаем такие сложности? a[i] = i%5

Comment: Не не знаю, тут про сложности не спрашивали. Простой вопрос - простой ответ. Но возьму на заметку

Comment: a[i] = i%6 на самом деле, а то там 5 тоже есть.